# JFileChooser > "Look in" weird names

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have a java application that uses JFileChooser on Win7. The weird thing is that sometimes (quite often) but not always - drive names look weird in 'Look in:' combo box:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what causes that and how to make it always show proper names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those come from system drives like My Computer, Network Neighborhood, etc.

The way I get around it showing the files like that is:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileView(new FileView() {

   @Override
   public String getName(File f) {
      String name = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(f);

      // If names is empty use the description
      if(name.equals("")) {
         name = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemTypeDescription(f);
      }

      return name;
   }
});
```

This way it is always pulling the names being displayed by the file system.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes (without changing the code) drive names are shown correctly and sometimes for no particular reason I see crap like like ::{20D......

Comment: @Artur Yes, so you can see if `name` is an empty string and if it is use `String name = FileSystemView.getSystemTypeDescription(yourFile);` instead

Comment: @Artur the ::{20D junk is just from not using FileSystemView to grab the correct system name, the blank names happen because `File.getName()` doesn't know how to translate the names for system level drives.

Comment: Just to make your answer more clear for the future readers - please add info about that in order to use your method one has to set new FileView for JFileChooser and then override mainly its getName method. BTW FileSystemView is an abstract class so to make it work  one must write sth like "String name = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName(yourFile);". After that I'll accept your answer so that you get more credit that you deserve.

Answer (score 2):

I want to share a little piece of code which explain the not so obvious behavior of JFileChooser.
On Windows there is a difference if you navigate on the filesystem in a CMD session or in the Windows file explorer.
For example you navigate to the root directory of drive `c:\`.

**CMD**

```
rem this will still stay in C:\ as there is no parent directory
cd ..
```

**Windows file explorer**

```
- the parent directory of 'C:\' is 'Computer'
- but 'Computer' is not a real directory and is accessed by an CLSID (Class Identifier
  for COM class objects), the incomprehensible '::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}'
```

The code to make this behaviour more clear.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class JFileChooserParentDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // the root directory of drive C:
        File file = new File("C:/");

        // get a view of the file system
        FileSystemView fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        // get the parent directory of our file
        File parentDir = fileSystemView.getParentDirectory(file);

        // get the Windows display name of this parent directory
        String displayName = fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(parentDir);

        // get the Windows type description of this parent directory
        String typeDescription = fileSystemView.getSystemTypeDescription(parentDir);

        // print out all the different values
        String printFormat = "%-50s: %s%n";
        System.out.printf(printFormat, "file.getAbsolutePath()", file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.printf(printFormat, "parentDir.getName()", parentDir.getName());
        // this absolute path is related to the directory from which you started the code
        System.out.printf(printFormat, "parentDir.getAbsolutePath()", parentDir.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.printf(printFormat, "fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(parentDir)", displayName);
        System.out.printf(printFormat, "fileSystemView.getSystemTypeDescription(parentDir)", typeDescription);
    }
}
```

This print out.

```
file.getAbsolutePath()                            : C:\
parentDir.getName()                               : ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
parentDir.getAbsolutePath()                       : D:\development\stackoverflow\playground\::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(parentDir)    : Computer
fileSystemView.getSystemTypeDescription(parentDir): System Folder
```

To solve the problem in the `JFileChooser` take the solution from @inquisitor.